# Trying to facet with geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a heatmap using ggplot2, in which each horizontal row is an individual subject's values of a variable over time.  However, I'd also like to group subjects within treatment assignment. When I try to use facet_grid, all facets contain EVERY subject number on the y-axis instead of only the subjects assigned to that particular treatment.  Consider the following example:

```
library(tidyverse)
subject <- rep(paste0("Subj", 1:6), 3)
trt <- rep(c("A", "B"), 9)
week <- rep(1:3, each = 6)
value <- sample.int(10, size = 18, replace = TRUE)
df <- data_frame(subject, trt, week, value)

ggplot(df, aes(x = week, y = subject, fill = value)) +
   facet_grid(trt ~ .) +
   geom_tile()
```

This creates two panels, designated trt A & B, but each panel contains Subjects 1-6.  I'd like to see Subjects 1, 3, 5 (only) in panel A and Subjects 2, 4, 6 in panel B.

Very new to R, so any help would be greatly appreciated!  Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = week, y = subject, fill = value)) +
   facet_grid(trt ~ ., scales = "free") +
   geom_tile()
```

[image]

Details are given under parameter `scales` in `?facet_grid`.

Comment: No problem @JimSmith; glad to help!